# Gap on top and side of entry door

Tags: doors, hinges

I know this has been asked by several folks on the forum, but I wanted to ask specific to my situation.

We live in a new construction home in Central NJ, just moved in this past September. When we contacted our builder, she refused to come out to take a look and said the issue is probably due to the weather.

Seeing as to how it's really cold out and New Year's weekend, before I call a professional to take a look, I wanted to see if there are suggestions on how I can fix the issue.

There is a gap on the top and left side of the door (opposite side of the hinges). The door also protrudes inwards in that same corner. Are there any diy fixes for this? I've attached pictures for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your door is warping. There's probably no way to fix the door itself, but there are a couple of things to do that can help.

1. apply or move the weatherstripping so that there's no air passing through
2. re-hang the door to split the difference of the warp between the top and bottom. This will never be a perfect solution, but it's done pretty regularly.

You should ensure that the door has been painted on the top and bottom edges, as this is one cause of warping. Also, you should make sure that moisture isn't being dumped onto the top of the door from the outside.

There's also the question of what warranty obligations the builder has to you. You'll need to consult locally, but they might be legally required to fix this. (And, in my opinion, a fix would be a new door. However, standards of what is acceptable vary from place to place.)

Comment: Door might be mis-hung rather than warped. Still, seems odd to me to have a door installed such that there's a clear straight path for air from outside to inside.

Comment: Mis-hung is possible, but I didn't see any lippage at the other 3 corners... maybe it's there and not obvious to me from the pics. (The other **very unlikely** thing that's possible is that the entire light on the knob side is set wrong.)